# HTML5 video not playing on safari when I removed muted property

Tags: html, css, video, safari

```
<video  poster="video/vr.png" id="bgvid" preload="auto" 
      playsinline autoplay muted loop >      
   <source src="video/VR-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="video/VR-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

When I removed `muted` attribute video stop playing on safari browser. I want the video to be audible

Comment: Please check if your markup complies with the [`<video>` Policies for webkit](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove it programmaticly.  It must Be unmuted via a user event like a click.